# Local audio Playback on Raspberry Pi while connected with Remote Desktop

Tags: python, permissions, raspberry-pi, remote-desktop, xrdp

i have a problem with my Raspberry Pi 4, equipped with the latest Raspbian. I have written an Python Script, which reads out some Data from an USB HID device (pyusb lib) and needs root permissions to do that. Additional my Script plays some Audio (pygame lib) through the AV Jack. This works well, as long as i have a monitor connected and work directly on the Pi.
I have installed xrdp to connect to the Pi via Win 10 Remote Desktop.
If i try to start my Script via remote Desktop with root privileges, i got an error when it comes to the Audio playback:

`xcb_connection_has_error() returned true`

If i start my Script via Remote Desktop without root privileges, the Audio Playback works well, but the USB access is not working. I have already tried to add a rule to the `udev/rules.d` to add the normal user to the usb user group with no effort.
Does someone have a solution to handle the Error with to xcb connection?

Many Thanks,
Daniel